# How can i use DockLayoutPanel in DisclosurePanel?

Tags: java, gwt

i,

I do have a DisclosurePanel. I would like to use a DockLayoutPanel (ui.xml) into this DisclosurePanel. I couldn't find any solution for this. Does anybody know?

I've tried setContent(EncoderDetails) and no result.

Thanks

```
    <g:DockLayoutPanel unit="PX" styleName="{style.panel}">
    <g:north size="54">
        <g:HTMLPanel>
            <table width="30%">
                <tr>
                    <td style='padding:0px 0px 0px 10px'>
                        <g:Label text="Target Details"></g:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style='padding:0px 0px 0px 10px'>
                        <g:TextBox ui:field="targetText" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:north>
```

```
    <g:center size="350">
        <g:HTMLPanel>
            <g:DisclosurePanel ui:field="disclosureDetails"
                stylePrimaryName='menu'>
                <g:header>Details</g:header>
                <g:VerticalPanel ui:field="vPanel">
                </g:VerticalPanel>
            </g:DisclosurePanel>
        </g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:center>

final DisclosurePanel operationsPanel = new DisclosurePanel("Operations");
operationsPanel.setStyleName("fill-layout-width");
operationsPanel.addOpenHandler(new OpenHandler<DisclosurePanel>() {
  @Override
  public void onOpen(
      OpenEvent<DisclosurePanel> event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    disclosureDetails.getHeaderTextAccessor().setText("Operations " + targetText.getText());
    encoderDetails = new EncoderCompositeDetails("encoderDetails");
    operationsPanel.setContent(encoderDetails);

    // RootPanel.get().add(operationsPanel);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. This is working in this time, but anyone have better solution, I'd like to know.

I'm not using DockLayoutPanel and north. Now ui.xml is start with HTMLPanel

Looks like DisclosurePanel is not like to DockLayoutPanel. I didn't try different type of panel.